# django-filter: TypeError at /goods/ __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am learning Django REST Framework. And I want to use the django-filter in django rest framework to choose the result I want.
I wrote a filter.py to get goods whose price is between pricemin and pricemax:

```
class GoodsFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    pricemin = filters.NumberFilter(name="shop_price", lookup_expr='gte')
    pricemax = filters.NumberFilter(name="shop_price", lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = Goods
        fields = ['pricemin', 'pricemax']
```

then I used this filter in view.py:

```
class GoodsListViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Goods.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GoodsSerializer
    pagination_class = GoodsPagination
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = GoodsFilter
```

when I run my project, there is an error like this:

```
TypeError at /goods/
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

I did not use argument 'name' in my code, so I have no idea about this error.
Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/goods/

Django Version: 2.0.3
Python Version: 3.6.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'DjangoUeditor',
 'users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'goods.apps.GoodsConfig',
 'trade.apps.TradeConfig',
 'user_operation.apps.UserOperationConfig',
 'crispy_forms',
 'xadmin',
 'rest_framework',
 'django_filters']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
```

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\Harry\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Harry\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Harry\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Harry\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Harry\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py" in view
  103.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Harry\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  483.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "C:\Users\Harry\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in handle_exception
  443.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "C:\Users\Harry\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  480.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Harry\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py" in list
  40.         queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

File "C:\Users\Harry\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py" in filter_queryset
  152.             queryset = backend().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)

File "C:\Users\Harry\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\django_filters\rest_framework\backends.py" in filter_queryset
  94.         if not filterset.is_valid() and self.raise_exception:

File "C:\Users\Harry\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\django_filters\filterset.py" in is_valid
  206.         return self.is_bound and self.form.is_valid()

File "C:\Users\Harry\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\django_filters\rest_framework\filterset.py" in form
  24.         form = super().form

File "C:\Users\Harry\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\django_filters\filterset.py" in form
  258.             Form = self.get_form_class()

File "C:\Users\Harry\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\django_filters\filterset.py" in get_form_class
  250.             for name, filter_ in self.filters.items()])

File "C:\Users\Harry\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\django_filters\filterset.py" in <listcomp>
  250.             for name, filter_ in self.filters.items()])

File "C:\Users\Harry\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\django_filters\filters.py" in field
  138.             self._field = self.field_class(label=self.label, **field_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Harry\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py" in __init__
  330.         super().__init__(max_value=max_value, min_value=min_value, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Harry\Envs\testvir2\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py" in __init__
  254.         super().__init__(**kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /goods/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From the [Migrating to 2.0](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/migration.html#filter-name-renamed-to-filter-field-name-792) guide,

> **`Filter.name` renamed to `Filter.field_name` (#792)**
>
> The filter name has been renamed to `field_name` as a way to disambiguate the filter’s attribute name on its FilterSet class from the `field_name` used for filtering purposes.

So, from **`django-filter==2.0`** onwards, use [**`field_name`**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/tips.html#filter-name-and-lookup-expr-not-configured) instead of **`name`**

```
class GoodsFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    pricemin = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="shop_price", lookup_expr='gte')
    pricemax = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="shop_price", lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = Goods
        fields = ['pricemin', 'pricemax']
```

Comment: Python's error message would have had me searching for years to fix that problem if I hadn't found this answer.